# Derivatives of a specific function

Tags: derivatives

We constantly work with functions at university, but this one is baffling me.
It's a simple one - yet I can't get my head around it and I get stuck after taking out f''(x) (second derivative).

Could someone walk me through it? Thanks in advance!
$
    \frac{(x^2+x+1)}{(x^2-1)}
$

Comment: Hm, what have you tried to do?  What did you get stuck at?  We need these pieces of information to write such amazing answers to you sadly.

Comment: I got stuck at 2nd derivative (ergo, f''(x)) - and precisely at the point where I've put it into trinomial.

Comment: Well, then you should at least include what $f'(x)$ is, how you got it, what you tried to do to get $f''(x)$, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

Your function can be written as

$$f(x)=1+\frac{x+2}{x^2-1}$$
$$=1+\frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{x^2-1}$$

$$=1+\frac{3}{2(x-1)}-\frac{1}{2(x+1)}$$

You can take it from here.

Comment: The fact that the denominator was factor-able should've made this obvious.  :D